# How to provide xml/json config to Release Management in TFS

Tags: powershell, tfs, release-management

I have a release build definition in Team Foundation Server 2015 update 3 on premise, which is the new web based version of release management. This makes use of an artifact that consists of multiple services that are needed to deploy. We have a Powershell script that is used to deploy all the services and configure the environment correctly.

Needles to say, every environment is different (different database, different configuration). The Powershell script that is used to deploy needs some configuration that is not easy to insert as plain variables via the variables tab in release management (because of objects/arrays). We want to use json/xml files for the configuration as input for the Powershell script that is used to deploy.

My question is, how can we manage these json/xml files for different environments (also for production) and be able to make them accessible for only the platform that it corresponds to in TFS? This without making environments be able to access/see configuration files that are not their own. Also without the configs being part of the code, and by that be available to all developers, which isn't desirable either.

Answer (score 0):

We store each part in different artifacts, so for you, depending on how you work you *could* have a CI produce a main "build" artifact, then a series of "dev", "smoke test", "qa", "pre-live", "production" (or however you name them) artifacts (which may just be configuration files etc).

<del>When you deploy your build, you can use the "get artifact" task to get the main build, and appropriate config for the environment you are working in.</del> Sorry I'm being a numpty, this is a task we wrote internally, I just use it too much to notice it's not built in.

We approach this in a couple of different ways.

One (or multiple) XML/JSON "transforms" file that you could use to update the default configuration (such as one to transform an app.config and update a connection string as you require), we use this approach with a variable/parameter passed in from the build, so we're essentially telling the PowerShell script to use a particular set of transforms.

What you could do would be to have your CI produce an artifact, plus drop in the config separately, so you could maintain them without relying on any weird transforms.  You can use the "Copy and publish build artifacts" tasks with an appropriate filter, and produce one artifact for your app, one for your dev config, one for qa config etc.

In some cases if you need to produce different packages (for deployment to cloud services etc), you can rerun the compilation step and put that whole thing/package into an artifact, so you'd have artifact_dev and artifact_qa... As long as you produce them from the same CI you should be able to get them in your artifacts staging directory (I believe) of the release.  Then your PowerShell just goes into artifactStaging/{environment}.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I can not find the "get artifact" task you are talking about, is this a custom task or does it require TFS 2017? Besides that, if I create a different artifact for every environment, this could add up to hundreds of artifacts for our production environments doesn't it?

Comment: Arg, sorry I'm such an idiot, we developed our own task to go to a named build and fetch a named artifact... I'll update my comment.

Comment: But again in this solution, in my case you would have hundreds of artifacts if you want one for every production environment. But If you have one artifact with a collection of all the configuration files, the release agent would always download all the configuration files of every production environment to the agents location, which can be inside the network of a customer. Both solutions doesn't seem ideal, or maybe I do not understand your solution completely.

Comment: Your CI build can produce many artifacts, they are saved to the server.  When the (Release) build is running it would download all the artifacts to the agent yes.  If you're setting up the agent on their premises, I'm not sure there is a silver bullet to this problem without going into weird/convoluted setups (such as storing their config in blob storage and having your setup program query this).  I assume you're installing agents on their premises as you don't have access to remotely access the target servers?

Comment: Your assumption is true, and in the situation you describe would result on all the configuration of every environment on the production system, and not only the configuration that is needed there.